# php setcookie, not expiring on browser restart

Tags: php, cookies

I set a cookie with the expire parameter set to 0 :

Then I redirect to another page where I check for the cookie. After browser restart, it still exists.

With "0" for expire, the cookie is supposed to expire when browser is restarting.

Setting `session.gc_maxlifetime` to a very low value didn't help.

EDIT : 
The complete 2 files :

Login page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>User Logon</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
/* These are our valid username and passwords */

$user = 'jonny4';
$pass = 'delafoo';

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    if (($_POST['username'] == $user) && ($_POST['password'] == $pass)) {

        if (isset($_POST['rememberme'])) {
            /* Set cookie to last 1 year */
            setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], time()+60*60*24*365, '/', 'stateful.example.com');
            setcookie('password', md5($_POST['password']), time()+60*60*24*365, '/', 'stateful.example.com');
            echo "you're logged in! (remembers)";

        } else {
            /* Cookie expires when browser closes */
            setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], 0, '/', 'stateful.example.com');
            setcookie('password', md5($_POST['password']), 0, '/', 'stateful.example.com');
            echo "you're logged in!";
        }
        header('Location: statefullogged.php');

    } else {
        echo 'Username/Password Invalid';
    }

} else {
    echo 'You must supply a username and password.';
}
?>

<h2>User Login </h2>
<form name="login" method="post" action="#"> <!--au lieu de action="login.php"-->
   Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
   Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
   Remember Me: <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" value="1"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login!">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Logged page (where cookie stays alive) :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>User Logged</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE['username'])) {
    header("Location: statefullogin.php");
} else {
    echo "username: " . $_COOKIE['username'];
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you closing all instances of the browser?

Answer (score 0):

If this test fails, then there's nothing else that can interact with keeping the cookie alive except for the browser...

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['session_only'])) {
  echo 'cookie exists';
} else {
  setcookie('session_only', 'testing_cookie', 0);
  echo 'cookie not found, setting new cookie';
}
```

Comment: Yes, it fails.  The cookie always exists after a browser restart.

Comment: So, php is wrong in saying that the cookie will be deleted after a browser restart ?

Comment: No, there's something wrong with your browser, this code functions perfectly fine for me. Is your computer clock correct? (just trying to think what it could be) Can you try in a different browser you don't normally use?

Comment: What about after a computer restart? All I can think is there's a browser instance remaining open when you think its all closed, check your systems task list to see if there's any outstanding instances of your browser running.

Comment: Even after a reboot of my ubuntu vm, cookie's still alive. Same on the windows 10 host.